# Как в календаре установить сегодняшнюю дату в атрибут 'max'?

Tags: html

Как в календаре установить сегодняшнюю дату в атрибут 'max'?

> `<input type="date" id="date" min="2015-01-01" max="...сегодня..." value="">`

Где '...сегодня...' должна быть написана дата сегодняшнего дня в настоящий момент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чисто на HTML никак, а на PHP легко!

```
<?php
echo "<input type='date' name='calendar' value='" . date("d-m-Y") . "'>";
?>
```

Или на js:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var name_input = document.getElementById('your_name')
    name_input.value = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
});
```

```html
<input type="data" name="calend" id="your_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let d = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');

    let dat = new Date();

    const dd = dat.getDate();

    const mm = dat.getMonth() + 1;

    const yyyy = dat.getFullYear();

    d.value = yyyy + '-' + 0 + mm + '-' + dd

    console.log(d.value); //  должна быть сегодняшняя дата
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).